# Can I take pickled plums (umeboshi) through USA Customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

I am living in Japan and my host mother is offering to give me her homemade [*umeboshi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umeboshi), or pickled plums. The plums do have a seed in the middle but because they have been pickled the seed can't grow.

Would USA Customs allow them through?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/snackexchange/comments/gwk38/iama_real_life_customs_officer_a_simple_set_of/ - banned "Any kind of processed stone fruit (think peaches) that still have the pit inside of them". Haven't found a definitive reference though.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, there should be no problems taking pickled plums into the USA.**
You just need to declare it on the declaration form, i.e - [Yes, pickled only.](http://www.immihelp.com/forum/showthread.php/22345-What-to-mention-in-customs-form-if-you-have-pickles-and-sweets-with-you)

[You can take any of these items into the USA](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/General%20List%20of%20Approved%20Food%20and%20Plant%20Products.pdf)

To make sure you have no problems in case you are searched, [check out the process.](http://redbus2us.com/us-port-of-entrypoe-procedures-%E2%80%93-video-2-min/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: great news!  phew!

Comment: Just make sure you declare it. ☺